# Python Django Dynamic Form View

Tags: python, django, view, dynamicform

Thank you in advance for the help.

One of the functionality of my web app, is making me to use a dynamic form system. I am not a fan of using third party applications on my web projects. Please kindly read the code to know if you can help out.

**View**

```
"""This view filters classgroup and supplies the students data to the template."""

def data_cull (request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session = request.POST.get('session', '')
        subclass = request.POST.get('subclass', '')
        arm = request.POST.get('arm', '')

        classgroup = ClassGroup.objects.filter(session = session, level = subclass, class_arm = arm)
        students = classgroup.student.all()
        return render_to_response('result/upload_result.html', {'students': students}, c)
    return render_to_response('result/upload_result.html', c)

def upload_result (request) :
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    if request.method == 'POST':

        data = request.POST.keys()
```

**Template**

```
<p> Input the exam scores of the students </p>

<form action = "" method = POST>
    {% for student in students %}
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="{{student.name}}" placeholder ="{{student.name}}">
    <label>Mathematics</label>
    <input type="text" name="{{student.name}}_{{mathematics}}">
    <label>English</label>
    <input type="text" name="{{student.name}}_{{english}}">
    <label>Chemistry</label>
    <input type="text" name="{{student.name}}_{{chemistry}}">
    {% endfor %}
    <input type = "submit"
</form>
```

I want to iterate through the `POST` values, and store them in the database. Does anyone have an idea of how I can do it?

Comment: Why don't you use django formset https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/formsets/?

Comment: i am using django 1.6; also, i do not really understand the formset system

Comment: Please add your related models also.